# Qt QUdpSocket readDatagram cannot get sender IP address

Tags: qt, udp, ip

```
Qt Version 5.10.0 (MSVC 2015, 32bit)
```

I have a PC which has a static host address("192.168.0.106"), and a device with an arbitrary IP address assigned by a router. I want to establish a UDP connection between them.

Qt has a udp demo called multicastreceiver, I modified the Receiver::processPendingDatagrams() function as followed:

```
QByteArray datagram;
QHostAddress senderIP = QHostAddress();
quint16 portx = 0;

while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams()) {
    datagram.resize(int(udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize()));
    udpSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &senderIP, &portx);
    statusLabel->setText(tr("Received datagram: \"%1\" @ %2:%3")
        .arg(datagram.constData())
        .arg(senderIP.toIPv4Address())
        .arg(portx));
}
```

and in the construction function:

```
udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 18427, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
    this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
```

I successfully received the udp message, but

```
senderIP.toIPv4Address() is 0, and senderIP.toString is NULL
portx is 64800 but it is wrong
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with these codes?

PS: I can get udp message and sender IP address and the right port number via a UDP debug tool(a PC program).

Comment: Try with `QNetworkDatagram receiveDatagram()` instead. Your code has some code smell due to manual buffer management etc. It's much easier to use `QNetworkDatagram`: it has all the data you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a known bug in Qt:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64784

This is fixed in Qt 5.9.4 - and I believe in 5.10.1 also.

See also [the commit](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=6a9d076e87f0c8aa4fb49bbcc2f56eefd85af2e3).